# No Windows Phone Custom Control Template in Visual Studio?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I can't see any such template so how does one develop such control ?

How do I put the control in the toolbox ? Does it use attributes like winform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your looking to create a custom control. Here's a walkthrough.

[Snowfall (User Control Sample) : Windows Phone 7 Tutorials : Compiled Experience](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/snowfall)

Comment: How do I put the control in the toolbox ? Does it use attributes like winform ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a UserControl?  They work the same as any other silverlight UserControl.

Comment: But I can only see Silverlight Class Library Template and no UserControl ?